# Security vulnerabilities when launching Shiny app in browser?

Tags: r, security, shiny, rstudio

I've been working on a Shiny app at my internship, and for multiple reasons, it would be ideal for the app to be launched in the browser rather than an RStudio viewer window. However, I am using very sensitive and protected data within this application that is stored on local servers, and am worried about the possibility of security threats to that data if launched in the browser. **Are any parts of the data files sourced within the app, or any of the processing done by the app, uploaded or connected to the internet in any way when using the browser? Do any data security vulnerabilities arise from running the app this way? Does downloading a data file through the Shiny app in a browser introduce it to the internet in any way? Or does everything remain local?** I have spent some time searching online and am only finding answers to Shiny security in regards to the shinyapps.io servers that you can buy, which are not what I am looking for information about. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Everything is run locally. The browser is only used because it renders HTML code into something usable to the human eye/mind. But at no point is there any access to the Internet (unless you specifically call for it in your code) when running an app off the IDE locally.

Comment: @Phil Thank you very much! That makes sense.